# Excel - Calculate time in specific time span

Tags: excel, date, time

I have to calculate the time until a machine is available again.
The work time is daily from 06:00am until 22:00pm.

If I simply add the time with the hours, the result looks like this.

```
| Job Duration (hours) | Start            | End              |
| 18,75                | 21.09.2017 06:00 | 22.09.2017 06:15 |
| 20,14                | 21.09.2017 11:30 | 22.09.2017 07:38 |
```

This is wrong for me, because the work time is only from 06:00am to 22:00pm.

I would like to achieve the following result:

```
| Job Duration (hours) | Start            | End              |
| 18,75                | 21.09.2017 06:00 | 22.09.2017 07:45 |
| 20,14                | 21.09.2017 11:30 | 22.09.2017 15:38 |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is Column "A" value 18, 75 implies?

Comment: The comma is the decimal separator. Assuming OP comes from Germany or somewhere similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example

[image: Broken down results]

To get your End time I calculate the ***actual time*** the job takes i.e non-working and working hours.
There's 16 hours in the working day (between 6 and 22) and there's 8 non-working hours (between 22 and 6).

```
=8*(INT(A2/16)+IF(60*((A2-INT(A2/16)*16)+HOUR(B2))+MINUTE(B2)>60*22,1,0))+A2
```

To break this formula down this:

1. Calculates the number of non-working periods by doing `INT(A2/16)*8` This divides the number of working hours into the job duration
2. I Then test if the job duration is going to take longer then a day using `IF(60*((A6-INT(A6/16)*16)+HOUR(B6))+MINUTE(B6)>60*22` This calculates whether the job would go past 10PM. I compare the two in minutes instead of hours for accuracy. If the job would go past 10PM I add on another non-working period
3. I then multiple the total number of non-working periods by the number of non-working hours (8)
4. And finally add the total of non-working hours onto the original job duration

All in all this calculates the amount of non-working hours + working hours to give me the ***actual time***

I then add the ***actual time*** to the start time using:

```
=B2+C2/24
```

to get my end time.

Then finally, I've combined the formulas to give you your answer in one column

```
=B2+(8*(INT(A2/16)+IF(60*((A2-INT(A2/16)*16)+HOUR(B2))+MINUTE(B2)>60*22,1,0))+A2)/24
```

Giving your results:

[image: Final Results]